# $\sum_{n=1}^{\phi{(m)}-1} \equiv 0 (mod m)$

Tags: number-theory

Let m, and $a>1$ be natural numbers such that gcd(a,m)=gcd(a-1,m)=1. Show that

$1+a+a^2+...+a^{\phi{(m)}-1} \equiv 0 (mod m)$

Proof:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\phi{(m)}-1} \equiv 0 (mod m)$

Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Euler's Theorem, if $\gcd(a,m)=1$ we have
$$(1+a+a^2+\cdots +a^{\varphi(m)-1})(1-a)=1-a^{\varphi(m)}\equiv 0\pmod{m}.$$
If $\gcd(1-a,m)=1$, we can multiply both sides by the inverse of $1-a$ modulo $m$, and obtain the desired result.